# iOS 17 Airdropped file not opening in our app and instead opening in files app

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios17, airdrop

Our application is configured to handle a custom file type with the extension .ptw. Until the release of iOS 17, when we used Airdrop to send a .ptw file, it would seamlessly open directly in our app on the receiving device. However, since iOS 17, we've noticed a change in behavior where the .ptw file is now being automatically saved to the Files app. To access it in our app, we must manually tap the share button and select our app from the sharing menu.

I'm curious to know if others have experienced this change as well, and whether this is the expected behavior in iOS 17 or We are missing some configurations to regain the previous behaviour.

If anyone has any insights, workarounds, or suggestions regarding this issue, please share them here.

Comment: Are you running build on Xcode 15? Or is this problem also happening with older builds that are pre-Xcode releases, that happen to be running in iOS17...

Comment: We are running the build from XCode 15.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/10696, I don't recall anything that would trigger this, but it should describe what changed in iOS17

Comment: Yes I am experiencing this and am also annoyed by the change!

Comment: The AirDrop Open With dialog is not supported on iPadOS 17 and later. If you AirDrop a file from a Mac to an iPad with iPadOS 17, the file will be opened in the default app for that file type.
There are a few reasons why Apple may have made this change:
* To simplify the AirDrop experience on iPad.
* To improve security by preventing users from accidentally opening files in malicious apps.
* To promote the use of Apple's own apps, which are more likely to be optimized for iPad.

Comment: To me it's even worse, as the flow of my app was: Airdropping an XML file from my Mac to my app on iPad. By using this airdrop open with dialog my app could be open and under the hood I could move the xml file from Documents to my desired folder. But now It's not possible to parse the URL that I am receiving via Airdrop.
I noticed the path of the URL after iOS 17 is inside of iCloud drive's Download folder. Does anyone know why the URL can not be parsed from this new path? And how to fix it?